# Words similar to Yes and No - Azure speech recognition

Tags: c#, azure, speech-recognition

I am looking for a way to understand words similar to Yes or No (Like sure, yeah, no way, not right now, etc..) without having to manually take each one of these into consideration.

Is there a way to do that with the speech API from Microsoft?

Currently, I have a list of "Yes"/"No" words which I compare the transcribed text to, but this does not scale well as you might expect.

Edit:
What I am trying to achieve is retrieve the user's intent during a scripted conversation with the user.
So for example I'll be asking the user:

```
System: "Do you wish to add another note?"
User: "Yeah, sure." or "Yes" or "Ok, why not?"
System: "Ok, listening..."
User: "This is going to be my first note"
System: "Note added."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but the Text Analytics API might help you.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/text-analytics/

Translate the audio to a text and then you can send it to the text analytics to retrieve the information about the sentence, including the key words that helped the algorithm to decide if this sentence is positive or negative.

### EDIT

Based on your added information, if you try to run the "OK, why not?" in the Text Analytics API, you will receive a high percentage in the sentiment field, which will allow you to continue with your flow.
[image]

Comment: I've edited the question to illustrate my goal - thanks

Comment: Looks like the Text Analytics will give you what you need. Check my edited answer.